# How to get JWT from Azure SSO Login

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on

I am using Azure SSO Login to get authenticated to our own application.
Everything works fine except the fact that I would like to have JSON Web Token (JWT) which I could use in order to make some API calls to Microsoft Azure after login.

Azure SSO does not return JWT after login, is there any way to obtain it?

Mirko

Comment: What kind of application is it? Azure AD offers various ways of acquiring access tokens to APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols. Which you use depends on the app's type and capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is cloud based app (Laravel in the backed, Vue.js in the frontend)

Comment: In that case you would use MSAL.js in your front-end to acquire tokens and authenticate the user (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser).

Answer (score 0):

Scenarios that you may refer to get idea in addition with @juunas suggestion:

This [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) tutorial of JavaScript single-page
application (SPA) signs in users and calls Microsoft Graph by using
the authorization code flow with PKCE. The SPA uses the Microsoft
Authentication Library (MSAL) for JavaScript v2.0.

---

This [scenario](https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/single-page-webapp-how-to-secure-your-app-and-your-api-with-azure-active-directory/) uses js frontend and php backend with azure ad which might give an idea

Its Flow :

1. A user accesses front end
2. If the user is not authenticated, he will be redirected to Azure Active Directory (AAD) to login
3. AAD will redirect (on success) with an authorization token
4. We’ll inject this authorization token into the calls made to the backend (to prove your identity)
5. The backend API will validate the authorization token and verify it against the issuer (AAD)

---

[Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory](https://blog.torib.io/2020/07/15/protect-an-api-by-using-oauth-2-0-with-azure-active-directory-and-api-management/)> This case registers two apps for azure AD - backend app and front end app ,uses validate-jwt  policy to validate the OAuth token

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I was looking also at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion could this be the way to create OAuth token? Mirko